# MySQL query to select specific resources

Tags: php, mysql

**Scenario:**

The school where I work at has already a system that handles resource reservation (racks with tv's, projectors, etc), however I was asked to make a quick-fix for today since the system has a problem, there's no way to make the resource only appear for a specific segment:

1-6th grade is a segment,
7-11th grade is a segment.

The system is made out of PHP and MySQL.

**Problem:**

Without creating a new table, I have to find a way to show a specific resource only to 1-3rd grade and another one only to 4-6th grade.

Here are the tables:

[image]

I added into the grade table a new column called `UNIQUERESOURCES`where I put a value of `1` to sections between `first and third grade` and a value of `2` to sections between `fourth and sixth grade`.

How can I show to grades from 1-3 grade ONLY those specific resources and from 4-6 grade ONLY the other specific resources?

Here is the current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.RESOURCEID, r.RESOURCENAME, rl.RESOURCELOCATIONNAME  FROM resource r
    inner join resource_location rl
    on r.RESOURCELOCATIONID = rl.RESOURCELOCATIONID
    inner join grade g
    on g.RESOURCELOCATIONID = r.RESOURCELOCATIONID
    inner join users_intermediate ui
    on g.GRADEID = ui.GRADEID
WHERE ui.USERID = '%s'
```

How can I fix this query to include the resources as follows:

Include `RESOURCELOCATIONID = 5` where `UNIQUERESOURCES = 1` if the user is in between `GRADEID 1-12`

Include `RESOURCELOCATIONID = 6` where `UNIQUERESOURCES = 2` if the user is in between `GRADEID 13-24`.

This is the part I can't figure out. Some help would be really appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Here are some pictures of the resources

Resources:
[image]

Grades: 
[image]

Users Intermediate (emails are censored in this pic):

[image]

As you can see, what I'm trying to accomplish is also include the resources that have `resourcelocationid = 5` or `resourcelocationid = 6` if the user teaches in grades that go from 1-3 or 4-6

Comment: add a where clause   ( RESOURCELOCATIONID = 5 and gradeid between 1 and 12  ) or ( RESOURCELOCATIONID = 6 and gradeid between 13 and 24  )

Comment: Although I posted an answer, clarification on 1-6th and 7-11th.  Is that a constant description within the "GradeName" column of the "Grade" table, and if so, what are all grade "Name" values exepcted.  Are they all simple like 1st, 2nd, 3rd... 11th?  Or do they vary on context / naming consistencies?

Comment: @DRapp I updated my answer, hopefully this clarifies what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: 'Without creating a new table...' Come on. Play fair.

Comment: Can you provide a more sensible and representative data set.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed this way:

```
SELECT  RESOURCEID, RESOURCENAME, RESOURCEDESCRIPTION,
    T3.RESOURCELOCATIONNAME, T2.RESOURCESTATUSNAME,
    T2.RESOURCESTATUSDESCRIPTION, T2.RESOURCESTATUSID
FROM resource          T1
INNER JOIN resource_status   T2 USING(RESOURCESTATUSID)
INNER JOIN resource_location T3 USING(RESOURCELOCATIONID)
INNER JOIN grade USING(RESOURCELOCATIONID)
WHERE T1.RESOURCELOCATIONID IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT RESOURCELOCATIONID FROM grade G
            INNER JOIN users_intermediate  UI
            ON G.GRADEID = UI.GRADEID
            WHERE USERID = "%s"
        ) 
AND (
    T1.RESOURCESTATUSID = 1
    OR (
       T1.RESOURCELOCATIONID = 5 
       AND (
           UNIQUERESOURCES = 1 AND GRADEID >= 1 AND GRADEID <= 12
           )
       )
    OR (
       T1.RESOURCELOCATIONID = 6 
       AND (
           UNIQUERESOURCES = 2 AND GRADEID >= 13 AND GRADEID <= 24
           )
       )
    )
```

Comment: this doesn't work. I think an IF statement should be used, but I have no idea where to place it and how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing sample data and confirming true context of your data and expected output, I would like to mentally describe via transitive association.

User "A" is associated with class/grade 1,2 and 3.

Looking into the Grade table, you find User "A" has grade information pointing to Locations "LH", "LR" and "LX" (arbitrary as to not confuse a location with a grade of 1-3 OR 4-6 (or other as later needed)).

Since we know the qualified "Locations", User "A" has access to ANYTHING found within the "LH", "LR" and "LX" locations.

Now, because the ResourceLocationID is in both the Resource_Location and the Resource table, the Grade table can actually join to each directly as the resource location table is nothing more than a lookup to get a descriptive name of where it is.  The multiple things IN the room are the resources.

So, the only thing my inner prequery "QualGroups" does, is get a list of the UniqueResources groups (either 1 or 2) a user has access to.  The next level is to get all DISTINCT locations under that 1 or 2 status.  Because IF a user is access for group 1 at location "LH" AND class group 2 at location "LH", you do not want duplicated resources for location "LH". I am getting the location name while I am at it. (result alias QualLocations)

Now, I can get the resources for those distinct qualified locations

```
SELECT
      QualLocations.ResourceLocationID,
      QualLocations.ResourceLocationName,
      R.ResourceID,
      R.ResourceName,
      R.ResourceDescription,
      R.ResourceStatusID
   from
      ( SELECT distinct
              RL.ResourceLocationID,
              RL.ResourceLocationName
           from
              grade G2
                 JOIN ( select distinct
                              G.UniqueResources
                           from
                              users_intermediate UI
                                 JOIN grade G
                                    ON UI.GradeID = G.GradeID
                           where
                              UI.UserID = "%s" ) QualGroups
                    ON G2.UniqueResources = QualGroups.UniqueResources
                 JOIN Resource_Location RL
                    ON G2.ResourceLocationID = RL.ResourceLocationID )
         as QualLocations
      JOIN Resource R
         ON QualLocations.ResourceLocationID = R.ResourceLocationID
```

Now, if you ONLY CARE about a very specific classification group, UPDATE the inner-most query joining the "Grade G" table to include the unique resource you are looking for... in this case either 1 or 2

```
JOIN grade G
   ON UI.GradeID = G.GradeID
   AND G.UniqueResource = 1    (or 2 if you only wanted 4th-6th grade)
```

Hope this helps you on your way.

Aside from posted question above, if you change your "UniqueResource" to have a numeric value of the specific GRADE it is vs the verbiage description of the grade name, the AND clause above could be simplified to something like

```
   AND G.UniqueResource IN ( 1, 2, 3 )   // for only grades 1-3
   AND G.UniqueResource BETWEEN 1 and 6  // ex: for grades 1-6
   AND G.UniqueResource > 6              // for any grade above 6th grade
```

Comment: this still only brings the 6 resources located on elementary and not the one located only on 1-3. I'll update post to show pictures of the data on the tables

Comment: @codeninja, As for your criteria for Resource Location 5 and grades 1-12 or Location 6 and 13+, Can you clarify.  Those would be for two completely separate queries correct?  Such as 1 query for Location 5, grades 1-12 and a completely separate query for 6 and 13+?  Or are you trying to pull ALL of them together.  Your question post is really unclear on it

Comment: Same query, the userid is a parameter (email) that is given by the `$_SESSION[]` of the application, depending on the user and it's relation inside the table `users_intermediate` I would have to show him or not the actual resource